# how to detect quickly if a string is zlib compressed?

Tags: python, zlib

What's the quickest way in python to determine if a string was compressed by zlib. I am using this currently.

```
def iscompressed(data):
    result = True
    try:
        s =zlib.decompress(data)
    except:
        result = False  
    return result
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way.

Comment: don't ever use a bare `except:` - it will get you false results. use `except zlib.error:` instead to catch the correct error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the first 2 Byte for the header information - it is, however, not 100% safe.

See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1950.html, chapter 2.2

Comment: You can use `ord()` on a single character (for instance, `ord(your_str[0])`) to get the integer value of that ascii character. You can then use bitwise operators (`&`, `|`, `^`) to check specific bits.

Comment: Thanks for that information, what should I exactly check? What the first 2 bytes should be if the string is decoded?

Answer (score 3):

While the only way to be 100% sure is to actually try to decompress it, you  can make a reasonable guess by looking for the zlib compression method + flags header bits:

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1950.html