# How do I check if a base64 encoded string is zlib compressed or not in node.js?

Tags: node.js, compression, zlib

I used `try/catch` like this.

```
try{
   const decompressed_data = zlib.inflateSync(Buffer.from(data, "base64"));
   return decompressed_data
}catch(err){
   return data
}
```

But How do I check if it's compressed with if/else, not try/catch.

I found [how to detect quickly if a string is zlib compressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322860/how-to-detect-quickly-if-a-string-is-zlib-compressed), but I don't understand the solution exactly.

Comment: What's wrong with try/catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using try/catch is the only reliable way to determine if it's zlib-compressed or not.

You can get an initial guess by checking to see if the first two bytes, after Base-64 decoding, make up a valid zlib header. See [RFC 1950](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1950) for the format. Those bytes need to be `0xxx1000 xx0yyyyy` (assuming that you are not expecting to provide a dictionary to the decompressor). The `x`'s can be anything. The `yyyyy` must be the one value that makes the sum of the first byte times 256 plus the second byte a multiple of 31.

There is a 1/2048 probability that random data will appear to be a valid zlib header, so this is not a very strong check. If this check says it's not a zlib stream, then it's not. However if it says it is a zlib stream, then it may or may not be a zlib stream. The only way to check from there is to do what you're already doing. If you're going to have to do that anyway, you might as well rely on the inflator to check the two header bytes as well. There is no need to do that manually yourself.